# Can I do six months in the USA on the VWP with a two week break in between?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens, motorcycles

I am British and therefore hopefully eligible for the VWP. I plan to ship my motorbike to the USA, fly from the UK to meet it there and ride around for three months.  Then in order to comply with the VWP I planned to fly to Brazil, spend two weeks there, then fly back into the USA.  I wanted to do another three months in the USA before I ship the bike back and fly home.  Is there a possibility that they won't let me back in and my bike will be stuck there?!

Comment: There's always a possibility they won't let you in for *any* reason, the final say resides with the IO. That said, your two weeks in Brazil will "reset" the 90 day VWP so technically you are allowed to go back

Comment: You might want to look into the issues of shipping a motorcycle in the USA. Since you're not accompanying it I'm not sure you can avoid the need to post a bond, pay duty and/or have it DOT/EPA certified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is always a possibility you will not be admitted. The visa waiver programme is intended for infrequent, short visits

Immigration may find two entrances at maximum length separated by such a short space of time suspicious. I suspect you would not be denied entry, but you may be subject to extra questioning on your second entry which could take a few hours and be quite unpleasant. You will need to be ready to show that you have a plan to spend your time, that you are a tourist, that you have sufficient funds to sustain yourself, and you do not intend to defeat any immigration rules such as by overstaying or trying to work. It is up to you to prove this, not for US CBP to prove the opposite.

It may be better to obtain a proper B2 six month tourist visa instead.

Comment: Agreed. As a note, it's worth mentioning that having a return ticket may not be enough, having enough funds and home ties should be proof enough that the OP doesn't intend to remain in the US

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful comments.  I am confident that I will be able to provide enough proof that I don't intend to overstay or to work in the US.  Is my plan to do two three month stints using the VWP likely to cause me problems in itself (because it might appear that I'm abusing the system)?

Comment: @TedPen It might do. It's hard to say, there are no firm rules about it. People using the visa waiver provision to the maximum possible extent more than once fit into a certain pattern, that may identify you as someone to be interviewed in a secondary inspection—a process that can take many hours. In your shoes I would investigate the cost and difficulty of obtaining a B2 visa. Still, I think you would be unlucky not to be admitted.

Comment: I'm playing it safe and going for the B2.  Thanks again.